# How do I rate limit my iOS network requests to one second

Tags: objective-c, ios

Many, if not most, web services have a rate limit for clients. Delicious says a client can make one request per second; Twitter has limits per end-point; I'm sure Facebook and Flickr and Foursquare have their own idea.

You can easily limit an iOS application to a single request at a time using an `NSOperationQueue`.

**But how do you limit an application to making, say, only one request per second?**

I've looked at the sample code by Apple, AFNetworking, ASINetwork and a few others, and none seem to solve this problem. This seems odd to me. I'll concede that I could be missing something *very* obvious...

Some parameters:

- Assume I have an `NSOperationQueue` for network operations and the request is an `NSOperation` (could also be a GCD queue I suppose, but this is what I've mostly been working with)
- The same rate limit is used for each request in the queue
- I'm looking for a solution in iOS, but general ideas might be useful

Possible solutions:

- `sleep` statement in the `NSOperation` (it's a queue/thread so this wouldn't block anything else)
- `NSTimer` in the `NSOperation`
- `performSelector:` in the `NSOperation` ([I patched ASINetworking to use this approach](https://github.com/sdarlington/asi-http-request), though I'm not using it and didn't push the change upstream)
- Start/stop the queue (using KVO?) to make sure the rate limit is not exceeded
- Special "sleep" `NSOperation`. This would be a task that the next network operation would be dependent upon
- Completely ignore the rate limit and just pause a bit when you get the "exceeded rate limit" error response

These all seem quite messy. Operations that sleep would likely prevent forms of "priority" queue. Starting/stopping the queue seems fragile. Ignoring the limit is rude.

To be clear, I have solved this problem. But the solution seems "messy" and somewhat fragile. I'd like to know if there's a better, cleaner option.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@implementation SomeNSOperationSubClass {
    BOOL complete;
    BOOL stopRunLoop;
    NSThread *myThread;
}

-(void) rateLimitMonitor:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    [theTimer invalidate];
}

-(void) main {
    myThread = [NSThread currentThread];

    NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self  selector:@selector(rateLimitMonitor:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [self doAsyncThing];

    while ((!stopRunLoop || [myTimer isValid]) && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
    complete = YES;
}

-(void) internalComplete {
    stopRunLoop = YES;
}

-(void) setComplete {
    [self performSelector:@selector(internalComplete) onThread:myThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(BOOL) isFinished {
    return complete;
}

@end
```

and in your async callback

```
    [myNSOperationSubClass setComplete];
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. This looks pretty much what I had in mind for my option 2 but since you show exactly how to do it and there are no dissenting views, I'm going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

New in iOS 13, this functionality is built in. Pass your communication trigger through the Combine framework's `debounce` operator and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix for the almost working solution provided by Edwin

```
- (void)main {
    for (double delay = 0.0; delay < 10.0; delay+=1) {
        [self networkCallWithDelay:delay];
    }
}

- (void)networkCallWithDelay:(double)delay {

      dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    // Your asynchronous network call goes here
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution, assuming you've already implemented your network module using other technologies other than NSOperation.

Use GCD to solve this problem. The following code introduces a 1 second delay to each network call. Pay close attention to the parameter for `popTime`

```c
- (void)main {

        for (NSInteger index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            [self networkCallWithDelay:1*index];
        }
    }
```

// Your network code goes here

```
- (void)networkCallWithDelay:(double)delay {

    double delayInSeconds = delay / 10.0f;

    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        // Your asynchronous network call goes here
    });
}
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect, it doesn't rate limit at all... All it does is do the network calls 1 second later, but just as many of them per second.

Comment: @einsteinx2 can you please read OP's question again, he asks.  "But how do you limit an application to making, say, only one request per second?
"

Comment: Yeah I understand that. Anyway I just reread your answer and see that you are in fact doing a simple form of rate limiting by dividing the delay into 10 seconds. I had missed the division and thought you were just doing all the call after a 1 second delay. Guess I was just tired, sorry about that. I've removed my down vote.

Comment: This does not work. The calls are all scheduled for t+1/10sec in the future.